# Update HTML Table when API is getting updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, woocommerce

I am just making a simple UI for display orders from Woocommerce shop. I am successfully getting the JSON response and put it into a HTML table. But I need to update the table without refreshing the whole page or table. Actually i need like, whenever Woocommerce get an order, the HTML table should get updated while highlighting the row. I am using AJAX to update the table but its not updating.
Note - I tried to set particular time interval for refreshing the page but i thought it won't be a good solution.
So far i got this below.

**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost/site/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=key&consumer_secret=key1",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var event_data = '';
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                /*console.log(value);*/
                event_data += '<tr>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.billing.first_name + value.billing.last_name+'</td>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.date_created+'</td>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.billing.phone+'</td>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.billing.address_1 + ", " + value.billing.address_2 + ", " + value.billing.city + value.billing.postcode +'</td>';
                event_data += '<td>'+value.total+'</td>';
                event_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $("#data").append(event_data);
        },
        error: function(d){
            /*console.log("error");*/
            alert("404. Please wait until the File is Loaded.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**

Any suggestions please.

Comment: does `$("#data").append(event_data);` doesn't show in your table ?

Comment: no. The table is not getting update unless i refresh the page.

Comment: does `console.log(data);` giving you right data .Also use `.html()` instead of `append()`

Comment: yeah it gives me the right data.

Comment: Does this `#data` exist in your html ? Please see if there are any error in browser console